# How to determine whether EC Point is on curve?

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have an ECPoint object "pointW" that I would like to check for whether it actually lies on some EllipticCurve "curve". How can I do this? I would prefer a solution using Java Crypto API but Bouncy Castle would also be fine.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more straightforward way but if you've got the `EllipticCurve` object, you can always just substitute the coordinates of your point into the equation of the curve.

Comment: There is so much functionality - especially BC provides many checking and conversion methods - that I thought there had already to exist a method like this and I didn't feel like re-coding the wheel. I finally ended up doing as you suggested and it turned out to be much less effort than I had expected.

Comment: @Thomas-    Am trying to check the same whether Qc(Public key) is on curve p-256 or not. I got the EC from public but how to validate, could pls share api in java. 
 EllipticCurve ec = publicKey.getParams().getCurve();